# Space on the left of my header

Tags: html, css

Why is it that I have space between my `header` and left border of the page? The space is symbolized by the black colour.

Heres the css that I'm using as well as the html I'm using for the header:

```
<header class = "header-style">
     <p>Android</p>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.header-style {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    background: #e95644;
}
```

Does the header naturally introduce space to the left and right when its positioned?

Thanks

P.S I forgot to mention I'm using Google Chrome!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Playground](http://jsbin.com/debebi/1/edit)**

Do you use any kind of ***CSS Reset***? If no Google about it but before you do that use

```
html, body{ margin:0; }
```

or

```
* {margin:0; padding:0;}  /* Global CSS Reset */
```

So basically you'll need to *reset* the styles the browser applies by default to Document elements: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

Also, while working with `position:fixed;` or `position:absolute;` you might want to set the element's `top` and `left` (or other) property.

Comment: resetting the global css properties did the trick - will start reading up about them soon

Answer (score 1):

It's better to work with reseted styles. In your case you can just add such css:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

But in general it is good practice to use reset.css, i.e. the one provided on meyerweb.com: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

It's work fine on jsfiddle,  [jsfiddle][1]. What browser do you use?

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/qfn6nco0/
```

Comment: actually it does not. You notice a small white border to the left. Wich can be get rid of by adding 
left: 0px;

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.header-style {
[..]
padding-left: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
```

Make sure your header is not in any DOM-Element other than the `<html>` tags